# Get top 5 values from 2d array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

> Array ( [ 20] => 154 [ 21] => 146 [ 24] => 230 [ 26] => 80 [ 33] =>
>   232 [ 113] => 100 [ 13] => 132 [ 12] => 146 [ 11] => 122 [ 235] => 110
>   [ 239] => 54 [ 248] => 162 [ 340] => 84 [ 352] => 76 [ 323] => 146 [
>   247] => 96 [ 372] => 150 [ 370] => 128 )

I need to be able to obtain the top five values from this array

The final result needs to look something like this:

```
Array(
     [ 33] => 232
     [ 24] => 230
     [ 248] => 162
     [ 20] => 154
     [ 372] => 150
)
```

If this can be done by simply re ordering the array, that is fine.

Comment: asort(); is there to sort array .

Comment: That looks like a simple one dimensional array but with user-defined keys rather than the typical chronological numerical keys. There isn't an array contained inside the initial array, is there? Either way, this wouldn't be very hard.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this, it will sort your array in descending order and slice your array for first 5 values

```
rsort($arr);

print_r(array_slice($arr, 0 ,5));
```

Comment: here I got Array ( [0] => 232 [1] => 230 [2] => 162 [3] => 154 [4] => 150 ) like this
i need Key also
like this 
Array ( [ 33] => 232 [ 24] => 230 [ 248] => 162 [ 20] => 154 [ 372] => 150 )

Comment: use arsort($arr). it will hold the keys also

Answer (score 8):

Using PHP's [`rsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php), you can sort the array in descending order. The first 5 elements are the largest:

```
rsort($data);
$highest = $data[0];
$second_highest = $data[1];
$third_highest = $data[2];
$fourth_highest = $data[3];
$fifth_highest = $data[4];
```

You can also use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to strip the top 5 into their own array after sorting (instead of separate variables like above):

```
rsort($data);
$highest_five = array_slice($data, 0, 5);
```

There are two caveats to this approach. The first is that the array-parameter is a reference to the original, so the original array is sorted (unless you make a copy first and sort the copy). The second is that it will re-index your array so the first index will be `0` regardless of whether it started out as index `33`, `56`, etc.

**UPDATE** (maintain index values)
To resolve the re-indexing of the array, you can instead use [`arsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php). This will perform the same as above, however, the keys will not reset to begin at `0`. All-the-same, you will also need to use the fourth *optional* parameter to `array_slice()` to tell it to "preserve keys" as it will also reset them. In-all, you can use the following to get the top-5 values into a new array:

```
arsort($data);
$highest_five = array_slice($data, 0, 5, true);
```

Comment: here I got Array ( [0] => 232 [1] => 230 [2] => 162 [3] => 154 [4] => 150 ) like this
i need Key also
like this 
Array ( [ 33] => 232 [ 24] => 230 [ 248] => 162 [ 20] => 154 [ 372] => 150 )

Comment: @Ras4U I've updated to show how to keep the array from being re-indexed.

Answer (score 7):

Reordering the array is called sorting and the "fastest" operation time you can get is O(nlog(n)) where n is the number of elements in the array.

It is faster (O(n)) to just iterate through the list and keep a list of the 5 largest.